# ValueError: No variables found for grid columns

Tags: python, seaborn

> Bonjour, Something is wrong

[Data source](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sdolezel/black-friday?resource=download)

> Code is:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df.head()
sns.pairplot(data = df.loc[:,['Gender','Age']],  hue = 'City_Category');
```

> That produces:

```
----> 1 sns.pairplot(data = df.loc[:,['Gender','Age']],  hue = 'City_Category');
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
-> 2096     grid = PairGrid(data, vars=vars, x_vars=x_vars, y_vars=y_vars, hue=hue,
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
-> 1233             raise ValueError("No variables found for grid columns.")
ValueError: No variables found for grid columns.
```

> What is wrong? Regards, Atapalou

Comment: you removed the "City_Category" column when you said: `data = df.loc[:,['Gender','Age']]`

Comment: You could try `sns.pairplot(data=df.loc[:,['Gender','Age','City_Category']],  hue='City_Category')`.  The most appropriate call would be  `sns.pairplot(data=df, vars=['Gender','Age'],  hue='City_Category')`.  Anyhow, if `hue` is the name of a column, it should be one of the columns of `data`.

Comment: This is the same. that fails. Probably, except for hue, it is necessary to use quantitative variables for this to work but it doesn't and that must be the reason why it fails. I think.